# How to filter in array except one column in angualr.js

Tags: arrays, angularjs

i am new in angular

i am creating table dynamically means i don't know what is my field name in table array.

in my table array there is one hidden property "Sr.No" which is fixed at all time 
but problem is that when i am search record the result will be display including "Sr.No" value. i am using '$filter' for searching
so is it possible that i am excepting "Sr.No" column in search result?

my array is :

```
var data = [{'Sr.No': '1','Name' : "abc"},{'Sr.No' : '2' , 'Name' : 'xyz'}];
```

Html code is

```
<tr ng-repeat= "value in  data | filter: SearchText">
<td ng-repeat = "list in value">
{{list}}
</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in multiple ways.

1) We need to use expression parameter in filter. Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). We can include something like

```
<tr ng-repeat= "value in data | filter: {$:SearchText, SrNo:'!' + SearchText}>
```

The problem with this approach is, when the SearchText is empty, the table is also empty. It looks odd.

2) The problem in 1 can be solved by writing a custom filter as below

```
myApp.filter('customFilter',
function($filter)
{
    return function(object, a)
    {
        a = a === undefined ? '' : a;

        if(a.length !== 0)
        {
            return $filter('filter')(object, {$:a, SrNo:'!' + a})
        }
        else
            return object;
    }
});
```

In the markup, you can use

```
<input ng-model="SearchText" >

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat= "value in data | customFilter:SearchText " >
            <td>{{value.SrNo}}</td>
            <td>{{value.Name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nagasandeepbondili/La6fm3h5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `SearchText.Name` that is search from only name field

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

        <input ng-model="SearchText.Name">

        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat= "value in  data | filter:SearchText">
                <td>{{value.SrNo}}</td>
                <td>{{value.Name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) 
{
    $scope.data = [{'SrNo': '1','Name' : "abc"},{'SrNo' : '2' , 'Name' : 'xyz'}];
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even your answer is returning the Sr. No...which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: means you dont want display it?